# How do I change the character's name?

Tags: brave-trials

There was a recent server merge that added the server suffix to everyone's username, in a generic `-sxx` format (with the `xx` being the 2-digit server number). I do not like this, and I want to get my original name back.

**Where in the game can I go to change my username?** Clicking the character does not give me this option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IGG has a link to change the name. In game, choose the 'Support' option, then 'Online Support'. On the web page that appears will be a custom URL for your character, where you can change the name **only once**, and **only after a server merge that affected your character**. Otherwise, there is no way to rename it.